# Getting DeadObjectException on uninstalling any app using adb

Tags: adb, uninstallation

On a fairly old non-rooted Galaxy Tab A-tablet I wanted to uninstall all the Samsung and Microsoft apps and most of the Google packages to make it faster. Using `adb shell pm uninstall -k user 0` I uninstalled 106 packages but after `com.sec.android.app.music` I suddenly can't uninstall packages anymore. Instead, I get a `DeadObjectException` and the tablet reboots:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall -k user 0 flipboard.boxer.app

    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:628)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.shellCommand(Binder.java:675)
            at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.runShellCommand(Pm.java:299)
            at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.runUninstall(Pm.java:674)
            at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.run(Pm.java:170)
            at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.main(Pm.java:103)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:315)
```

It looks to me like pm needs something that isn't there, so I might have uninstalled something that it needs. My question is, how do I find out what it was, and, assuming it wasn't the Samsung music app, why did it function correctly until after I installed that?

In an attempt to start over I have reset the tablet to factory settings and all the apps are there again, including the music app, but even now I get the same error when attempting to uninstall any of them.

Comment: First, I noticed that user needs some dashes to look like `--user` Second are you sure that is the package name? "clipboard.boxer.app" because general but not always the case it starts with a com.package.name

Comment: OP also posted on [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/getting-deadobjectexception-t4036273), just in case the issue has been resolved there but not here yet.

Comment: @AndrewT Sorry for the cross posting but my question got no response there which made me wonder if I even found the right forum for this problem. Can you tell me if it is?

Comment: @Lilfuzzybunny007 Thanks for the double dashes suggestion. I will try it when I get home tonight.

Comment: @Mr.Wrong no worries :) I accidentally found your thread on XDA while researching for this issue, so I decided to link it here... just in case there are additional details posted on there but not here. FWIW, this question is on-topic on here (issues faced by Android end/power-users).

Comment: Are you able to uninstall other packages or is it only this package that fails to uninstall? Have you tried to reboot the device?

Comment: @Robert I get this error with any package I attempt to uninstall. The above is just an example.

Comment: So it appeared @Lilfuzzybunny007's suggestion worked. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that user needs some dashes to look like `--user`

Second are you sure that is the package name? "clipboard.boxer.app" because general but not always the case it starts with a `com.package.name`